# Curl php youtube

Tags: php, youtube

Hi I am trying to build php youtube api without a Zend function

this is what I have till now:

```
function upload() {
    $files  = $_FILES;
    $name   = $files['file']['name'];
    $type   = $files['file']['type'];
    $size   = $files['file']['size'];
    $tmp_nm = $files['file']['tmp_name'];

    $data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@'.$tmp_nm);

    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);

    echo 'Size '.$size;

    $headers = array( 
        "Authorization: AuthSub token=".$this->auth,
        "GData-Version: 2",
        "X-GData-Key: key=".$this->dev_key,
        "Content-length: ".$size, 
        "API_XML_request"
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/action/GetUploadToken');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->user_agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION ,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);

    if($this->get_info)
    {
        $this->curlget_info($ch);
        }
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r($output);

    return $output;
}
```

The errors I get:

### Output 1

```
Array ( [token] => TOKEN ) Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => 0016.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\php178D.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 4216 ) ) Size 4216
Google       
Error

Length Required

POST requests require a Content-length header.
```

### Output 2

```
Array ( [token] => TOKEN ) Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => Film.wmv [type] => video/x-ms-wmv [tmp_name] => D:\wamp\tmp\php11D3.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 96589 ) ) Size 96589
Google       
Error

Length Required

POST requests require a Content-length header.
```

I am using [this guide](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#Uploading_the_Video_File).

I am trying to solve this for 5 days and I asked couple irc channels and forums. A friend linked me here to ask, I hope someone will help me :))

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a developer key so I can't help you out directly, but clearly Google has a problem with your http header so you have to find out what you're sending in the header, not the message body.  The best way to do this is to inspect the packet on the wire as it leaves your machine.

So install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), start it up on your WAMP server, start capturing packets, do your test, and then look at the http connection in the packet.  Make sure it's what you expect.

Or maybe there's a way for curl to write the packet to a file instead of the server for debugging purposes.  I don't know.

Also it's a long shot (and would rely on them being out of spec), but I noticed that you and that other person you linked to have "Content-length".  Try "Content-Length" to match the example.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the answer, but in the example page, they put quotes around the authsub token:

> Authorization: AuthSub token="DXAA...sdb8"

Maybe try that?

Comment: http://www.google.fr/support/forum/p/calendar/thread?tid=2189bc104e39ecb9&hl=fr

same question without answer :S (that's from someone else)